# No pdf is being produced while using moderncv (most likely because of special icons)

Tags: miktex, texmaker, moderncv

I'm trying to write a résumé using modern CV. The problems I encouter are strangely similar to those tackled [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99686/no-pdf-is-being-produced-while-using-moderncv/99688#99688). I tried the solution suggested there, to no avail, hence this post. Here is what I am trying to compile :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\name{Pierre}{Gibberish}
\phone{0000000000}
\email{abcd@mail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

The warnings I got when trying to compile are the following :

- you have requested package modercvheadii but the package provides
  modercvheadii
- you have requested package modercvbodyi but the package provides
  modercvbodyi
- you have requested package modercvfooti but the package provides
  modercvfooti
- Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 15--15
- Font shape U/fontawesometwo/m/sl' undefined using
  U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 17.
- Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

I tried both \maketitle & \makecvtitle they both showed the same error. If I omit the \maketitle then it runs & only a pdf with whatever I put after is produced.

I suspect that this has to do with special icons like mobile or email icons on the address lines (which were the problem in the post I linked above) but, as I said, the fix doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Texmaker with most updated Miktex. Can anybody please help?

Comment: I don't know where the warnings come from, but I have the same errors with Ubuntu/TexStudio and online (overleaf.com).
I also have those errors with the examples given by the package.

Answer (score 3):

Compile the file with XeLaTeX. It runs smoothely. With pdflatex I get the same errors as you.

edit://
Version 2.0.0 of the `moderncv`package on github provides several templates. The `classic` template uses a different iconset as can be seen in the *.sty file (cf. [here](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncvstyleclassic.sty))

```
% symbols
\moderncvicons{marvosym}
```

The `casual` Theme uses

```
% symbols
\moderncvicons{awesome}
```

In the project's [Changelog](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/CHANGELOG) you can note the following:

> version 1.5.1 (29 Apr 2013)
>    - made sure that XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is in use before loading the awesome icon  set and if not, revert to the marvosym icon set.
>
> version 1.5.0 (23 Apr 2013) [...]
>    - added a new icon set: "awesome" (using the icons from the Font Awesome font).

It is my guess that the 'fallback' method as described in 1.5.1 ceased working with the new version. Therefore the necessity to use `XeLatex` explicitly, since no fallback loads the old symbols that are compatible with `pdflatex`

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you have problems.  You are right, that you got several warnings, but all of them are not real problems at last, because you get a pdf file and the only difference could be the glyph for special symbols for a telefone, an envelope etc.

But let us check the warnings. The first three are:

- you have requested package modercvheadii but the package provides
  modercvheadii
- you have requested package modercvbodyi but the package provides
  modercvbodyi
- you have requested package modercvfooti but the package provides
  modercvfooti

This warnings are caused by an error in the current class `moderncv`, that has to be corrected by the class author.  As far as I remember (but I didn't found the answer now) there was a question where @egreg answered how one can avoid these warnings.  But the resulting pdf is the same, with or without theese warnings.

The next warning is:

- Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 15--15

line 15 is the line with the command `\makecvtitle`. That means that inside this command or macro is something written causing this warning.  To get rid of this warning the author should change the code of macro `\makecvtitle`, but an underfull box does usually no harm.  You can ignore it in this case.

The last two warnings are:

- Font shape U/fontawesometwo/m/sl' undefined using
  U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 17.
- Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

You get this warning because you compiled your MWE with `pdflatex`, but in the class a font is used that is not available with `pdflatex`.  So LaTeX changed the font shape.

To get rid of this warning add the line (mentioned by @hatetheplot's answer)

```
\moderncvicons{marvosym}
```

before `\begin{document}` to advice LaTeX to use an available font. 
The difference is the layout of the used symbols for phone, email etc.

So at last this is the only real existing "problem" with your code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\name{Pierre}{Gibberish}
\phone{0000000000}
\email{abcd@mail.com}

\moderncvicons{marvosym} % font runs with pdflatex without warning

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Result with `marvosym`:

[image]

and without the added line:

[image]