# Moderncv template.tex is not compilable after MikTex and moderncv update

Tags: miktex, compiling, texstudio, moderncv

I wrote my CV using the `\moderncv` package just recently. All worked fine until I updated MikTex and the moderncv package (via the MikTex package manager). Now I use MikTex 2.9 and moderncv 2.0.0 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. Unfortunately, all my beautiful CVs are no more compilable.

Even worse, when I try the template given on CTAN (template.tex):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      


\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be 
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

TexStudio prompts the following errors:

- Command \name already defined. \newcommand*{\name}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqmU.jpg){{\namefont#1}}
- Undefined control sequence. \moderncvstyle
- Missing \begin{document}. \moderncvstyle{c

I have to admit that I am a Tex newbie and have no idea where to start. Could somebody please help me to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

Here is the *file list from the log file* which hopefully helps to clarify the problem.

```
*File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter c
olor scheme: blue
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
template.out
template.out
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 27.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `template.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 )
```

**EDIT**

And here are the *first two complete error messages* from the log file:

First:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \name already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Second:

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.5 \moderncvstyle
                  {casual}                             % style options are '... The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

**EDIT**

When I check the packages named in the log file against another users result after compiling (see accepted answer) some differences strike me. First, I have some packages in an *older version*, albeit installing MikTeX just two days ago:

- graphics.sty (2014/10/28 v1.0p)
- trig.sty (1999/03/16 v1.09)
- graphics.cfg (2007/01/18 v1.5)

Then there is one package which I found in my list which is not on the accepted answer:

- moderncvcolorblue.sty (2015/07/28 v2.0.0)

And finally a couple of packages not in my list:

- moderncvstylecasual.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0
- moderncviconsawesome.sty    2015/07/28  v2.0.0
- fontawesome.sty 2015/07/30 v4.4.0
- fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
- fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
- moderncvheadii.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0
- moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0
- ufontawesometwo.fd 2015/07/30
- moderncvfooti.sty 2015/07/28 v2.0.0
- moderncvcolorblue.sty 2015/07/28 v2.0.0
- epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5
- grfext.sty 2010/08/19 v1.1
- ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6
- omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6
- omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6
- omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6
- umvs.fd
- mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1
- omslmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6

Also my MikTex Settings look different:

[image: MixTex Screenshot]

Does anyone learn more from that than me?

Comment: ModernCV have changed and the new version break the compatibility with the previous one. The error could be due to this

Comment: @RomainPicot Thanks, Romain. I would nevertheless expect that the template that the author of the package uploaded works. Do you receive any error messages when compiling the file?

Comment: I Cannot test the code on my current computer perhaps later. However, are you sure to use moderCV 2.0?

Comment: When I open up my MikTex package manager, scroll down to moderncv, click on Properties, it states: "Name: moderncv; Date: 2015-08-04 22:01; Version: 2.0.0; Maintainer: Xavier Danaux". So I would say: I am pretty sure that it really is version 2.0.0.

Comment: What compiler did you use? PdfLaTeX? This does not work anymore: you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Indeed, I used PdfLaTeX. Considering your recommendation I changed the standard compiler in TexStudio to XeLaTex and subsequently pressed F6 (for compiling) but this resulted in the same error messages. Same for LuaLaTeX. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile with `pdflatex` the following MWE without any errors and only three warnings, which are caused by an error in the `moderncv` class.

The difference to your MWE is that I added two lines

```
\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome % for pdflatex!
\setlength{\footskip}{37pt} % to avoid warning ...
```

to get rid of the warnings for `fontawesome` and `\footskip  is too small`.

If I compare my resulting list of used packages and versions

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)  <============
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter compatibility patches
moderncvstylecasual.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: casual
moderncviconsawesome.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: awesome
fontawesome.sty    2015/07/30 v4.4.0 font awesome icons
fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
moderncvheadii.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 2
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1
ufontawesometwo.fd    2015/07/30 Font definitions for U/fontawesometwo.
moderncvfooti.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter footer variant: 1
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: blue
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
  295654.out
  295654.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
    umvs.fd
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
  omslmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

I see that my system used an newer `graphics.sty` than yours so the problem of yours could be a not current MiKTeX system and some other packages which are not listed in your list.

Please copy **my** following MWE and compile it on your system.  It should compile without errors. If not, your systems seems to be faulty. Compare the resulting list with mine above.

Changed MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}

\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome % for pdflatex! <===========
\setlength{\footskip}{37pt} % to avoid warning ...          <===========


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

To check if you are using an local texmf tree please open the MiKTeX settings, choose root and compare with the following image:

[image]

You see my used localtexmf tree marked with the red arrow.

To be sure which `moderncv` is used you can check the logfile. At the beginning you will find something like:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.29)  26 FEB 2016 16:04
entering extended mode
**./295654.tex
(295654.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncv.cls"
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
```

In the last line you can see the directory of my `moderncv.cls` used.

Your given message `\name already defined` means to me, that in your code or in your used class a wrong command is used:

```
\newcommand*{\name}[1]{{\namefont#1}}
```

In the current class `moderncv` command `\name` is defined to get two parameters, first and last name. If the other things did not help you should search for this line `\newcommand*{\name}[1]{{\namefont#1}}` and comment it out.

With a current MiKTeX and a current `moderncv` compiling my MWE results without an error using `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

Another try would be to reinstall MiKTeX (not only install it, afterwards also run the MiKTeX package manager to be sure that all packages are up-to-date.  **That seem not to be** as far as I can see at this moment.

With the given informations I can not say more to help you.

Comment: using `marvosym` solves the `fontawesome` error because it lets `moderncv` load the old symbols that don't need `fontawesome` and thus `xelatex`; check my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290488/no-pdf-is-being-produced-while-using-moderncv-most-likely-because-of-special-ic/290908#290908

Comment: To see an instruction to create a local texmf root directory for Miktex (which is the solution for the error as it is mentioned above) you can see this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex/69484#69484